# Centralized CI for Multiple Git(*) Repositories

Tags: git, continuous-integration, devops, webhooks

I have a project which requires complex automation of git repository workflow (github, gitlab, etc - at this point git source vendor doesn't matter). Here is the scenario:

I have 20 people who will provide authentication to their git platform account and will fork my private repository.

Then, when they update and push code to their fork, I want to have a cloud/self-hosted devops project, which will pull their code and validate it with unit tests (challenge #1).

The output status of the pipeline (passed or failed) will be sent to my server to track their fork build status (challenge #2).

Are the above steps possible with any technologies out there? If not, I am open to alternative solutions, but the basic requirement is:

People will have only read-access to my code, but i will need to programmatically validate the build output of their code with unit tests.

I've been thinking about this requirement for a long time, but couldn't come up with any solution. Maybe there is something fundamentally wrong with this requirement? Maybe i shouldn't be using Git, but a centralized version control?

Basically I want to know the build status (passed failed) when people fork from my repo and build the project either locally or push to their fork.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Edit:

Think of it this way: I will setup unit tests for the people in my initial repo, and they will have to develop features to pass the tests, and I want the final unit test passing result to appear somewhere on my server.

Comment: Is there any reason you want to force people to create a fork of your original repository? Github/Gitlab both provide branch locking/protection features. This would allow you keep all of the work within one repository, the 20 other people would create personal/feature branches and you could dictate that only you be allowed (through admin branch protections) be allowed to merge code into the main master branch.

Comment: You can do as @BenW suggested with one repo and branch protection which you can implement with githooks as well, it is nice because in gitlab CI this would mean you don't even need to write any custom test code. or otherwise make your Jenkins server or other CI receive a webhook that is generated for every push event on the forked repos. This would have to be configured seperately by every dev, for only a minor gain in isolation

Comment: Very nice question. @IlyasAssainov branch protection is an option for you as previous comments mentioned? With branch protection you will need to configure several rules. Example: only dev-joe must push to branch called feature-1. Only dev-jane must push to feature-2, etc. You have 20 devs :$.  If you are working with external developers like consultants, provider or freelancers, *fork* is recommend because developers just need *read* permission. I developed a jenkins plugin called *easy-webhook*. I think it would help you. Let me know if you are interested